# Getting unsupported operand types after upgrade to php 5.5.9 from PHP 5.2

Tags: php

Getting unsupported operand types after upgrade to php 5.5.9 from PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.27 
code is:

```
$iNewestVersion = str_pad($aRecord->any + 1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: `string str_pad ( string $input , int $pad_length [, string $pad_string = " " [, int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT ]] )` So focus on that first argument... string input + integer 1?  What is that intended to do?

Comment: `var_dump($aRecord->any);`

Comment: The code is intended to increment a file name to ensure that it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that this error is thrown when an improper math operand is used in conjunction with an array.  For example: combining an array and a scalar with '+'.

https://glot.io/snippets/eqt5oz4rd5

I would be willing to bet money that `$aRecord->any` is an array.

Comment: I split the code into two lines:     $aNewest = $aRecord->any + 1;
                   $iNewestVersion = str_pad($aNewest, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
The second line throws the error now. Of the four parameters, $aNewest is the most suspect.

Comment: Have you dumped the contents of $aNewest?

Comment: I replaced this construct with a DateTime string to ensure that the filename generated would be unique. I don't really understand the object operators '->' or '=>' yet. It is certainly true that the original code worked in version 5.2 but throws an error in 5.5.